# Atom Editor: CMD + R => No Symbols Found

Tags: python, c, atom-editor

For some reason, Atom doesn't seem to recognize function tags properly with the default plugin it has mapped to CMD + r. I've tried completely uninstalling and deleting Atom and it's files and reinstalling to get the function detection to work properly, but to no avail.

Function detection does not work in C++ or Python, for me. Instead of just recognizing functions in my Python scripts, it will even list my numpy imports etc. Somethings pretty wacky with it.

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

[image: The result of hitting CMD+r in the Atom.io application.]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution from an atom github [issue comment](https://github.com/atom/symbols-view/issues/173?#issuecomment-222352841) about the same problem, launching Atom from command line will make it work.

`cmd+r` maps to `symbols-view:toggle-file-symbols` command, which using `ctags` to generate language-specific symbols. `ctags` will generate temporary symbol list file inside your `$TMPDIR` directory , but that environment variable is not known when Atom launched from Finder.